# DiscordJS v14 guildMemberAdd Event doesn't send the embed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When I run my bot and someone joins, nothing happens.Why nothing happens?

Event file:
`const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
name: "guildMemberAdd",

```
/**
 * @param {GuildMember} member
 */
execute(member) {
    
    const wcChannel = member.guild.channels.fetch("1155899900161171586")


    console.log(`${member.name.toString()}` + "has joined!")
    

    const wcEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle("Welcome")
    .setDescription(`${member.name.toString()}` + 'has joined the `SeaMystics`-Server!\n\n**Welcome!**')
    .setColor("#4ba511")
    .setTimestamp()

    wcChannel.send({embeds: [wcEmbed]})
}
```

}`

Main file:
https://haste.l4zs.de/urahanipuv.typescript

Send a message to a channel, when someone joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wcChannel` is a `Promise`. You'll need to **await** it or get the channel from cache [suggested].

---

#### Fetching

```js
const wcChannel = await member.guild.channels.fetch('1155899900161171586');
// ...
wcChannel.send({ embeds: [wcEmbed] });
```

---

#### Get from `cache`

```js
const wcChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('1155899900161171586');
// ...
wcChannel.send({ embeds: [wcEmbed] });
```

---

Source: [GuildChannelManager](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildChannelManager)